# SQL DATEADD Function Removing Week Ends

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2016, recursive-query

I need to add five days to the "2020-12-01" date. But here the scenario is while adding five days to "2020-12-01" date we should not include the Saturday (2020-12-05) and Sunday (2020-12-06).

I have tried with DATEDIFF with filter options in where conditions.. but I am unable to get the solution.
Can any one please help me to get it done. (Expected Output : 2020-12-07)

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler with a brute force approach, by enumerating the days in a subquery, decrementing the coutner for non-weekend days only:

```
declare @dt date = '20201202';
declare @no_days int = 5;

with cte as (
    select @dt as dt, @no_days as no_days
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt), 
        case when datename(weekday, dt) in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') 
            then no_days
            else no_days - 1
        end
    from cte
    where no_days > 1
)
select max(dt) as res from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3d2581d0ca301357423c28714d2a93fc)** (SQL Server 2016):

```
| res        |
| :--------- |
| 2020-12-11 |
```

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.